# Error When Preventing User to Bypass URL using CanActivate on FormGuard

Tags: javascript, angular

I've this code but when I bypass to step4, it doesn't redirect to step1 but still go to the step4. I think the syntax has some error?

```
if (this.router.url === '/product/edit/:id', {queryParams: {step: 1}}) {
    console.log(this.router.url === '/product/edit/:id', {queryParams: {step: 1}})
    return true;
} else {
    alert("Please complete step 1")
    this.router.navigate(['product/edit/:id'], {queryParams: {step: 1}} )
    console.log(this.router.navigate(['product/edit/:id'], {queryParams: {step: 1}} ))
    return false
}
```

I expect where someone can't bypass the step, everything should be from step 1 then step 2 and else.